# is there any way to convert byte array to blob object on client side in node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to get blob object from byte array client side without actual downloading file

Client side where I want to pass blob object =>

```
request.get('/api/get/video/blob/'+d1+'/'+d2+'/'+d3)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                   console.log("err="+err)
                } else {
                   console.log("data="+res)
                   if(res)
                   {
                    var uploadVideo = new UploadVideo();
                    uploadVideo.uploadFile(access_token,res// need actual blob object to pass @ res);  but what I get is byte array see following code
```

Server side=>

```
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/get/video/blob/{d}/{s}/{x}',
        handler: function handler(request, reply) {
            const {d,s,x} = request.params;
            const key = d+'/'+s+'/'+x;
            var bucket = 're.render-previews';
            var params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key
            };

         s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            console.log("coming back");
            if (err) {
                console.log("err=>");
                console.log(err);
               // reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log("data=>");
                console.log(data);
                reply(data); // where I get byteArray 
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: `on client side !== in node.js`

Comment: sorry I wanted to say client side / node js (using npm)

Comment: in web development client side is the stuff that runs in the browser. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming . so i guess you are meaning server side. Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line of code worked for me 
**var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(BYTEARRAY)], { type: 'video/mp4' });**

Comment: But how to import Blob? import statement I cant use . require is not working either

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(BYTEARRAY)**.buffer**], { type: 'video/mp4' });