# Byte array length getting increased after saving to MySql

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js

Hi I save a byte array using nodejs mysql library. My issue is, the byte array I have is of length 9459. But when I insert into mysql and read it back , it is giving me an array of size 32504.

Below is my SQL query which I am executing from nodejs

```
 const query = "INSERT INTO spreaddata.workbook  SET `user_email`='" + userEmail + "', `workbook_data`='" + workbook_data + "'";
```

Below is my Select query

```
const selectQury = "SELECT * from spreaddata.workbook WHERE user_email='name@company.com';
```

Here workbook_data  is the column of type blob in mysql. When I inspect the byte array recieved it is having a length of 32504. Why the length is getting increased.

I am resubmitting this question because clearly this is not a duplicate question

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to create SQL, use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: Question got closed but the link given pertains to SQL injecttion. My query was not at all related to preventing SQL injection. Not sure how this question is duplicate

Comment: The solution is the same, use a prepared statement to substitute variables into SQL.

Comment: const query = 'INSERT INTO spreaddata.workbook  (user_email,workbook_data) VALUES(?,?) ';
    sql.query(query, [jsonData.userEmail, '['+jsonData.workbook_data+']'])

I modified the query but still same issue

Comment: There's no need for `'[' + `. Just use `[jsonData.userEmail, jsonData.workdbook_data]`

Comment: The whole problem is that you're converting the byte array to a string, so you're getting its printed representation instead of the byte data.

Comment: code: 'ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW',
  errno: 1136,
  sqlState: '21S01',
  sqlMessage: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",
  sql: "INSERT INTO spreaddata.workbook  (user_email,workbook_data) VALUES('name@company.com',80, 75, 3, 4

Comment: I get above error when I run the query you suggested

Comment: Does this help: [convert byte array to blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399544/is-there-any-way-to-convert-byte-array-to-blob-object-on-client-side-in-node-js)?

Comment: No not working . Need to import Blob to work.. But import allowed only in  modules. require statement also not working

Comment: I think this question deserves reopening as clearly none of the solution is working and it is not related to SQL injection prevention

Comment: I've reopened. You can edit the question to show your attempt to employ all the techniques I linked to, then someone can help get it working.